# where is example of iOS Bluetooth LE peripheralManager didReceiveWriteRequests

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, bluetooth

I need an example implementation of function didReceiveWriteRequests which runs at a Bluetooth iOS peripheral when data is written to it by the central iOS device doing a 'writeValue:' .

But I've searched web and cannot find example.  Apple docs still have no sample code.

Comment: I've complete BLE tutorial, please share your mail id. i'll provide you code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I got it working.  Here is my working code:

```
// Processes write command received from a central.
- (void)peripheralManager:(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheral didReceiveWriteRequests:(NSArray *)requests
{

    CBATTRequest*       request = [requests  objectAtIndex: 0];
    NSData*             request_data = request.value;
    CBCharacteristic*   write_char = request.characteristic;
    //CBCentral*            write_central = request.central;
    //NSUInteger            multi_message_offset = request.offset;

    // Face commands this PWR RX to advertise serno UUID?
    int total_write_requests = 0;
    if([ write_char.UUID isEqual: [CBUUID UUIDWithString: YOUR_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID]] )
    {


        // Read desired new_state data from central:
        unsigned char* new_state = (unsigned char*)[request_data   bytes];
        my_new_state = new_state[0];
        #endif
        NSLog(@"        - advertise serno UUID: %s", my_new_state ? "TRUE" : "FALSE" );

        // Select UUID that includes serno of PWR RX, for advertisements:

        ++total_write_requests;
    }

    if( total_write_requests )
        [peripheral respondToRequest:request    withResult:CBATTErrorSuccess];  // result = success
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"_no_write_request_FAULT !!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you How to initiate a request from the central?

Comment: This also doesn't take into account all of the requests in the array?