# Central writing characteristic to Peripheral (iOS Core Bluetooth)

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, cbcentralmanager, cbperipheral

Okay, so I've looked through a thousand tutorials and other Stack Overflow threads (so please don't list as duplicate without answering the question) and I cannot work out how to use this functionality.

I have followed this tutorial:
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-7-sdk-core-bluetooth-practical-lesson--mobile-20741

I have a system where a central can connect to a peripheral and read a characteristic from it.

I am now trying to get my central to rewrite the data within the characteristic but am finding the write line that I have called just being ignored.

I have declared my characteristic within my peripheral class as such:

```
self.transferCharacteristic = [[CBMutableCharacteristic alloc] initWithType:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:TRANSFER_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID] properties:CBCharacteristicPropertyNotify|CBCharacteristicPropertyWriteWithoutResponse|CBCharacteristicPropertyRead value:nil permissions:CBAttributePermissionsReadable|CBAttributePermissionsWriteable];
```

And in my centralManager I have called

```
 [peripheral writeValue:[@"rewritten!" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] forCharacteristic:characteristic type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithoutResponse];
```

But the line is ignored. Can anyone talk me through what might be wrong? Do I need to add a method to my peripheral class?

Also, I've tried doing it WithResponse but it still doesn't even call that method from the peripheral either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you still stuck with the problem?

I guess your problem is persisting due to the fact that you have not implemented `didReceiveWriteRequests` method.

```
// Processes write command received from a central.

- (void)peripheralManager:(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheral didReceiveWriteRequests:(NSArray *)requests
{

    CBATTRequest       *request = [requests  objectAtIndex:0];
    NSData             *request_data = request.value;
    CBCharacteristic   *write_char = request.characteristic;
    //CBCentral*            write_central = request.central;
    //NSUInteger            multi_message_offset = request.offset;

    // Face commands this PWR RX to advertise serno UUID?
    int total_write_requests = 0;
    if ([ write_char.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:YOUR_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID]] )
    {


        // Read desired new_state data from central:
        unsigned char *new_state = (unsigned char *)[request_data   bytes];
        my_new_state = new_state[0];
        #endif
        NSLog(@"- advertise serno UUID: %s", my_new_state ? "TRUE" : "FALSE" );

        // Select UUID that includes serno of PWR RX, for advertisements:

        ++total_write_requests;
    }

    if ( total_write_requests )
    {
        [peripheral respondToRequest:request    withResult:CBATTErrorSuccess];  // result = success
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"_no_write_request_FAULT !!");
    }
}
```

Comment out the  `[peripheral respondToRequest:request    withResult:CBATTErrorSuccess];`, as in your case you are using CBCharacteristicWriteWithoutResponse.

Code taken from: [where is example of iOS Bluetooth LE peripheralManager didReceiveWriteRequests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498205/where-is-example-of-ios-bluetooth-le-peripheralmanager-didreceivewriterequests)

Comment: Thank you for replying. Yes after a good day of coding I worked out and as you say it was just me misunderstanding the framework. At one point I was even putting delegate methods within the peripheral class! Half a day of pulling hair out and actually reading through the apple guide properly and I worked it out!

Comment: I am glad to know that it worked out. At one point of time, I was also in the same state as yours due to lack of proper insights. But in the end it all worked out. I also suggest you this sample repo [https://github.com/KhaosT/CBPeripheralManager-Demo]. Also, please accept my answer. :)

Comment: A random question, is there any other way of adding characteristics to a service than: _transferService.characteristics = @[char1,char2]?
I ask because I want to set up it's characteristics from a preexisting NSArray of characteristics? (e.g. I won't know the number of characteristics being added so I can't hard code it).

Comment: Yes! you can. [THIS](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOs/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBMutableService_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CBMutableService/characteristics) link specifies the parameter for setting characteristic as NSArray. I haven't tried myself but it would work. Check this [link](https://github.com/liquidx/CoreBluetoothPeripheral/blob/master/CoreBluetoothiOSPeripheral/CoreBluetoothiOSPeripheral/LXCBPeripheralServer.m#L75) for more.

Comment: The fact I didn't think of just passing it an NSArray is somewhat embarrassing. Thanks so much again! :)

Comment: No worries. I am a newbie to Objective-C. So, I have done much worse. ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66147/discussion-between-tushar-goyal-and-tom-cornish).